# Using white space in a char array in a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, whitespace

so I realize this is technically a duplicate question, so I apologize for that, however my code is acting strange and I'm at a loss. I am not a programmer, I'm not even taking classes, but someone asked me for some help on an assignment and I was going back through old programs I wrote for classes and decided to play around and see if I could make them more efficient. So, here are the code snippets that I am having errors with, I would post the entire code but it's long and 98% of it is not relevant to my question anyways...

```
class Exam {    
//properties
private:
   char m_fileName[50];
public:
   //Default Constructor
   Exam() {
      m_fileName;
   }

   //functions
   void setFile(){
       cout << "Enter the name of the Exam: ";
       cin >> m_fileName;
       for(unsigned int l = 0; l < 50; l++)
       {
           m_fileName[l] = toupper(m_fileName[l]);
       }
   }

   char* getFile(){
        return m_fileName;
    }
};
```

In `main` I create an array of `Exam` objects called `testFile[50]`. It goes to a menu with a switch statement, blah blah. When I choose to create a new test file, it goes to the following code:

```
 case 3: {
        testFile[f].setFile();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << endl << "Enter the amount of questions, Max. of 50: ";
        cin >> numQuestions;
        if (numQuestions > 50) {
        throw -1;
  }
  ofstream write(testFile[f].getFile());
```

So, here is the issue I can't seem to solve. I'd like to be able to type test files such as "Test A" or "Test B" or whatever, and have the char array `m_fileName` read in the white space. I know, to typically do that, you need to use `getline` or some other form, because "cin" stops reading when it hits white space. Well, literally any other form of input other than how it is, throws:

> 3 [main] chrisjohnson_ip3 9684 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to chrisjohnson_ip3.exe.stackdump

directly after "Enter the name of the Exam:   " and other times it will throw it when it asks to enter the amount of questions (without letting me input anything). I'm sure it's something really stupid that I'm missing, but I've been trying to figure this out for hours, so I figured I would call in the big guns. If you need me to post any more of the code or be more specific on something, please let me know. Thank you for your time and knowledge :)

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `char m_fileName[50];` is the root of all evil in this code. Replace it with `std::string m_fileName;` and fix all compilation errors until it runs again.

Comment: `Exam() {
    m_fileName;
}` Huh??

Comment: @Yousaf, why not?

Comment: Thanks for the debugging link, I'll check it out...I would much rather learn how to fix my own problems, but I've come to the end of my line of knowledge, so I figured I would ask here ;) After I read and try that process I'll edit my post if I still have questions. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a debugger to step through your code. It makes finding the bug much more easy.

However, I can point out some bugs in your code:

**First** off, what is *m_filename* doing in your constructor as a standalone?

```
   Exam() {
      m_fileName;
   }
```

If you want to have an empty constructor, then you can just do the following (this is just my way):

```
   Exam() {
      ;
   }
```

---

**Secondly**, you misuse *m_fileName* in your class functions. While you declare this char as an array that will hold 50 char values, when you accept input in the line:

```
   cin >> m_fileName;
```

You do not specify which of the 50 blocks of memory allocated to the my_fileName array get the inputted char. This alone should be causing a compilation error.

---

**Another thing**: this whole part of your code seems to be buggy. I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Maybe you can explain it in the comments box or update your question post.

```
   cout << "Enter the name of the Exam: ";
   cin >> m_fileName;
   for(unsigned int l = 0; l < 50; l++)
   {
       m_fileName[l] = toupper(m_fileName[l]);
   }
```

I'm not sure exactly what setFile() should be doing, so I cannot provide any fixed code for a solution.

---

Also, just as some advice, you can also change the data type of my_fileName to a string data type, as I'm assuming that The exam names that are input are not just 1 character in length.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So, the ultimate end goal of this program is to allow a user to create a bank of Test files. When they create a new file, they are given the option to create a certain amount of questions, and those can be TF or multiple choice. Once all of the questions are created, they are returned to the main menu where they can display all created tests, load a test, or display a test. Everything works, I get no compilation errors or anything (I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2 FYI). However, when using "cin >> m_fileName;" I am unable to use whitespace.

Comment: I have tried using getline, I have tried using string instead of char...when I do those, I get problems when I try to read the file (ex. ifstream input(testFile[t-1].getFile()); works, but only with cin >> m_fileName), I get type mismatch errors when I try to use a string instead of char for m_fileName

Comment: The last bit of your comment, about the buggy code, that is just asking the user to enter a name for the test file, and then I'm converting it to all upper case, just to make it easier on the eyes and ignore case input from the user

Comment: Have you tried using getline() for char values instead for string values? See the first example in this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/)

Comment: Instead of doing `cin >> my_fileName`, try doing this: `getline(my_fileName, 50)`.

Comment: I have tried getline() and I get the error as described at the end of my question

Comment: In that case, I would strongly recommend you to use a debugger. Step through your code line-by-line with the debugger. I believe πάνταῥεῖ posted a link on how to use a debugger above. You can then update your post and tell us which line is causing the problem, that would make sorting the problem much easier.